# A change to zbar-sdk tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

There is a tag [zbar-sdk](/questions/tagged/zbar-sdk) on SO, but [tag:zbar sdk] is something that regards only to iPhone backend of [zbar](/questions/tagged/zbar). I see some questions, maybe 10%, regard to zbar in general or to other ports, like Windows or Linux. I suggest adding also a [zbar](/questions/tagged/zbar) (or [zbar-other](/questions/tagged/zbar-other)) tag and explain that it's about non iPhone questions. In the same time an explanation should be added to [zbar-sdk](/questions/tagged/zbar-sdk) tag, that it's only for iPhone questions.

I think having 2 separate tags for zbar is the best option. I could get only non iPhone questions with [zbar](/questions/tagged/zbar) query. But if you prefer to have only one, then it should rather be "zbar".

This is not very important, but since I started trying to change this (by flagging [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9366658/772981) as an example) and was adviced to post a retag-request - I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the tag on [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9366658/772981) to [zbar](/questions/tagged/zbar), but then I also voted to close it as off-topic.

Having a distinction between [zbar](/questions/tagged/zbar) and [zbar-sdk](/questions/tagged/zbar-sdk) doesn't seem *urgent* since there are so few questions about either, but no harm in being more precise I suppose.

You should definitely update the tag wikis for both tags to indicate the distinction, and then retag any of the questions that aren't actually about the SDK.

Comment: Thanks. It was an out-of-place question indeed. Thanks for the new tag. I submitted wiki editions for both zbar tags. I took xsl tags as a template for tag excerpt and notes on their specific usage.